# Inheritance in C#. How we can avoid overriding of the caller?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a Base class something like -

```
BaseClass
{
    public performOperations ( Operator operator) 
    {

        switch (operator)
        {
            case addition:
                performAddition();
            case subtraction:
                performSubtractio();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void performAddition()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void performSubtraction()
    {
    }
}
```

I have derived class as follows

```
public class DerivedClass extends BaseClass
{
    protected new void pertformAdditon(){}
}
```

Now in order to override the function `performAddition();` I have to override `performOperations(Operator operator)` with the same code.

How else we can design this?

Comment: I can not understand why you use Static is it require?

Comment: "design this" - can you please [edit] the question to explain what exactly you are trying to design? From half-broken half-Java code it is kind of hard to figure out your the actual goal... (and fix code formatting while you are editing)

Comment: @Praveen change `protected new void` to `protected override void`. If you encounter problems *post your actual code* and an example that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Simply using a proper C# program with virtual and override [works as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZOV466). Post *real* C# code that demonstrates your problem

Comment: "pertformAdditon" is spelled differently as "performAddition" - typo only in the question or in your code?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Yes I changed the new void to override void. It's working fine as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make your "perform" helper methods `protected virtual` and **not** `static`. Then `override` them in the derived class.

Comment: I have done this but still performAddition() is being executed unless I override performOperations()

Comment: You will need to post that code where you did it, I cannot possibly find out what went wrong in code I cannot see.

Comment: @Paveen `virtual` and `override` work. They're used in all .NET applications for almost 20 years. If your code has a problem, *post the actual code* and an example that actually reproduces the problem. Demonstrating that `override` works is very easy